# Running tensorflow with tmux on Ubuntu server error

Tags: python, ubuntu, tensorflow, anaconda, tmux

I am trying to run a deep learning program using tmux. However it seems like tensorflow is not available.

To start the tmux environment i run:

```
ubuntu@ip-xxx-xx-x-xx:~/xxxx/xxxx$ tmux
```

Then inside the tmux environment I run:

```
ubuntu@ip-xxx-xx-x-xx:~/xxxx/xxxx$ source activate tensorflow_p36
(tensorflow_p36) ubuntu@ip-xxx-xx-x-xx:~/xxxx/xxxx$ python
Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan 16 2018, 18:10:19)
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

Importing other packages than tensorflow such as PIL or cv2 works fine. Importing tensorflow outside of the tmux environment the works.

I am running this on an ubuntu 16 AWS server. What could be the issue?

Comment: are you sure, the tensorflow is installed inside your virtual environment?

Comment: When you say virtural environment do you mean inside tmux? There is no problem to importing tensorflow outside of tmux.

Comment: Ya, check that without tmux, `source activate tensorflow_p36` this I suppose is you're activating a virtual environment.

Comment: I see what you mean now! I still get the same error though

Comment: if `tensorflow_p36` is the virtual environment, the error tells that you don't have tensorflow installed there. Can you show me the outcome of doing the same outside tmux.

Comment: `(tensorflow_p36) ubuntu@ip-xxx:~/xx/xx$ python`
`Python 3.6.6 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jun 28 2018, 17:14:51)
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.`
`>>> import tensorflow
/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters >>>`

Comment: I see, did you do this before you typed python in the terminal `source activate tensorflow_p36`

Comment: I just noticed that is seems like tmux is running 3.6.4 while I normally use 3.6.6

Comment: Yes before I ran `python` i ran `source activate tensorflow_p36`

Comment: It's not probably running tmux would change your python version, it's something to do with your virtual environment which has python 3.6.4

Comment: I am using the same virtual environment both inside and outside tmux though

Comment: Your output doesn't shows so, first do `source activate tensorflow_p36` and do `python` and check, if that's the same.

Comment: `(tensorflow_p36) ubuntu@ip-xx:~/xx/xx$ python --version
Python 3.6.6 :: Anaconda, Inc.`    
`(tensorflow_p36) ubuntu@ip-xx:~/xx/xx$ source deactivate`   
`ubuntu@ip-xx:~/xx/xx$ python --version
Python 3.6.4 :: Anaconda, Inc.`

Comment: In this case, I think you could see and change the path of python inside the tmux session. This is strange, that inside tmux it's picking your system python.

Comment: So I did the same test with the versions inside tmux now. Turns out the versions work the exact same way as they did outside of tmux. That means, system python is 3.6.4 and environment python is 3.6.6.

Comment: Then your problem should be solved right?

Comment: Actually yes! It seems like it!

Comment: That is cool, so tmux is just a screening software, it got no accord of its own to change your env as much as I know.

Answer (score 2):

To wrap this up. As @user2906838 pointed out the problem was that I was inside anaconda virtural environment before I ran tmux. When I exited the environment before running tmux and entered the environment inside of tmux everything worked as usual.